# Puppet storeconfigs confusion

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppetmaster, puppetdb

I'm fighting with Puppet storeconfigs of many hours and finally I found one thing which confusing me. I would like to set up storeconfigs, but when I set storeconfigs and storeconfigs_backend values in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf files [master] section it doesn't work. But when I test put those values in [main] section it some how works.

Why Puppet ignore [master] section configuration while their documentation said that storeconfigs belong into [master] section?

I using Puppet 3.8.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.

> https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/latest/connect_puppet_master.html
>
> To enable saving facts and catalogs in PuppetDB, add the following
>   settings to the [master] block of puppet.conf (or edit them if already
>   present):
>
> ```
> [master]
> storeconfigs = true
> storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
> ```

There is my puppet.conf file at beginning.

```
$ cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

I got same answer from Puppet

```
$ sudo puppet config print | grep ^storeconfigs
storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs_backend = active_record
```

I set storeconfigs and storeconfigs_backend values into puppet.conf file [master] section, but it doesn't work and storeconfigs value is still false.

```
$ sudo puppet config set storeconfigs true --section master
$ sudo puppet config set storeconfigs_backend puppetdb --section master
$ sudo puppet config print | grep ^storeconfigs
storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs_backend = active_record
```

I just test put those values into puppet.conf file [main] section, and it works.

```
$ sudo puppet config set storeconfigs true --section main
$ sudo puppet config set storeconfigs_backend puppetdb --section main
$ sudo puppet config print | grep ^storeconfigs
storeconfigs = true
storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
```

Comment: The --section master would be needed in the query and the setting of the config item. So try ... "puppet config print storeconfigs --section master". [main] is the global section, so setting something there means every section "inherits" it.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet has rearranged their config files a couple of times, and the sections that things live in.  I've given up trying to keep track of it all, and I instead just use `puppet config print | less` and see which section Puppet wants particular config items in today, and then just put them there.

Answer (score 1):

## Configuration queries

To see the configuration visible from "puppet master", you can use

```
puppet master --configprint all | grep storeconfigs
```

or

```
puppet master --configprint storeconfigs
puppet master --configprint storeconfigs_backend
```

…which will use the configuration in the defaults in the [main] section, as well as the [master] specific section.